# Dynamically display image in IOS xamarin - nitWithContentsOfFile:' method returned nil

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a portable xamarin application with some "specific overrides" for android and ios.

I have a content page with image that need to be downloaded from server.
Since the image is not "public" on the server I cannot use a simple url to add the image to the Image control.
So my code is downloading the image, save it locally and then pass the image url to the Image control:

```cs
        string filePath = GetThumbnailPath();
        Image img = new Image
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            WidthRequest = 150,
            HeightRequest = 150,
            Source =  FileImageSource.FromFile(filePath),
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 10)
        };     
        layout.Children.Add(img);
```

On android everything works great.
On IOS the image is saved to:

```cs
        string directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string filePath  = Path.Combine(directory, "thumbnail.jpg");
```

but when the page is loaded the application crash with:
System.Exception: Could not initialize an instance of the type 'UIKit.UIImage': the native 'initWithContentsOfFile:' method returned **nil**.

I cannot change the image to be a bundled resource (its **dynamic**) and cannot make the server call public (its an handler require header parameters or cookies)

Answer (score 2):

On iOS you can save image to local storage with this code:

```cs
        var rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        var folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Images", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("image.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var buffer = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

        using (Stream stream = await file.OpenAsync(PCLStorage.FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
        {
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        return file.Path;
```

Than, you can show that image with:

```cs
        var imageSource = new FileImageSource { File = filePath};
        MyPicture.Source = imageSource;
```

Where MyPicture is defined with:

```
        <Image x:Name="MyPicture">
```

Comment: Nope...System.Exception: Could not initialize an instance of the type 'UIKit.UIImage': the native 'initWithContentsOfFile:' method returned nil.

It is possible to ignore this condition by setting MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.

Comment: I copy/paste this from project where it works as expected. You can try it in demo project and if it works change in the way that you are using it in your project. When it is making this exception?